# this code doesnt print out the enquiry id?

Tags: mysql, while-loop

```
   $do_select = mysql_query("SELECT EnquiryId FROM formsubmission WHERE name='$name' AND phone='$phone' AND email='$email' AND message='$message'") or die(mysql_error());
 if ($do_select)
{

while ($selected_data = mysql_fetch_assoc($do_select))
{
    // Show status


echo "<center>Your Enquiry was successfully submitted and your enquiry id   is </center> ";


 echo "<center><b>" .$selected_data['EnquiryId'] ."</b></center>";

}

}
```

enquiryid which is auto increment and fetched from my sql table ,,i tried to echo after the if(do_select) condition ,it works which means that the query is selecting the enquiry id from database ,but not printing the enquiryid ,the while condition has some problem ??

Comment: `echo` the select statement and `var_dump($selected_data)` and let us know what you see

Comment: I feel like a broken record here on Stack Overflow, but you shouldn't be using the `mysql_query` function, and you certainly shouldn't be building queries with string interpolation. What if someone enters their name as `'; DROP DATABASE; --`?

Comment: alfasin,the output then is Resource id #5resource(5) of type (mysql result)

Comment: troy -so what should i do instead ???

Answer (score 0):

i dont know why you doing this if statment. while you have already the `or die` statment.

try this.

```
      $do_select = mysql_query("SELECT EnquiryId FROM formsubmission WHERE name='$name' AND phone='$phone' AND email='$email' AND message='$message'") or die(mysql_error());

 while ($selected_data = mysql_fetch_array($do_select))
 {
  // Show status


 echo "<center>Your Enquiry was successfully submitted and your enquiry id   is </center> ";


 echo "<center><b>" .$selected_data['EnquiryId'] ."</b></center>";

  }
```

Comment: the action to redirect the form to a page is working but on that redirected page nothing is being printed,its just a blank page,n earlier this same code was working without any modification,i 'm not getting why this code isn't working now ????

Comment: your solution didn't work,the problem is with the while loop ,if i remove the loop n echo something it is being printed but nothing inside the while loop is being printed!!

Comment: this code is good , you have something else you hiding it. show your whole code then we can help you.

Comment: i have posted another question with my whole code,plss assist there,its title is same as this

Comment: @user2606532 i couldnt find it can you give the link to it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18002154/this-code-doesnt-print-the-enquiry-id